# A purely geometric proof that pi is irrational?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, pi

I am well aware of the analytical proofs. I was wondering if a purely geometric one was/can be found.

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_π_is_irrational

Comment: Another good ref https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the OP asked for a geometric proof

Comment: Geometric proofs of irrationality usually relies on the fact that some continued fraction is heavily structured, like $\varphi=[1;1,1,1,\ldots]$ or $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,\ldots]$. The continued fraction of $\pi$ does not exhibit any nice structure, hence I am partial to believing that a *purely geometric* proof of $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be designed. On the other hand, it is also true that $\arctan x$ has a nice *generalized* continued fraction.